# PHP4 for ARM fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, php, arm

I am looking for an ARM RPM of PHP 4, specificity to install on Fedora 17, however I cant seem to find one anywhere.
I assume this is most likely down to ARM not being supported by Fedora in the age of PHP4?

Hopefully either you know where I can grab the RPM or maybe a way to compile from source or some other install method?

Thank you and hopefully someone can help! 
(if you need more info just ask!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to find an RPM anywhere for that. Your best bet is compiling fro source. This is not actually too difficult.

1. Make sure you have a compiler.
2. Download the source code from php. (link: https://www.php.net/get/php-4.4.9.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror)
3. Unarchive.
4. Read instructions in the "INSTALL" file.

Answer (score -2):

you can try with this command for installing php4

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php4
```

hope it will work in your machine.

Comment: Not going to work, fedora uses YUM as its package manger and I have already search the fedora repo's for the package. But thank you